# FILTER_VALIDATE_URL and $_GET, copy string after $_GET parameter

Tags: php

I use:

```
if (filter_var($_GET['paste_here'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    echo ???;
}
```

And I'd like as soon as user enters a site after .php?paste_here = that specific site to be displayed on echo. But I don't want how to print. Any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: `echo $_GET['paste_here']`

Comment: it's question about how to print something in PHP it's really to simple and can be found easily in google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out if param exists, so:

```
if (isset($_GET['paste_here']) && filter_var($_GET['paste_here'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    echo $_GET['paste_here'];
}
```